# Uncertainty principle when the expectation value of commutator is zero

Tags: quantum-mechanics, heisenberg-uncertainty-principle, commutator

I'm reading section 4.3 of Introduction to quantum mechanics written by David Griffits.

The book states that the product of the standard deviation of two components of angular momentum is greater than or equal to the expectation value of one component of the remaining angular momentum multiplied by half of h-bar. I learned that the z component is related to the magnetic quantum number, but if m is 0, can the x and y components of each momentum be obtained respectively?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, the fact that $S_x,S_y$ cannot be measured simultaneously follows from the fact that $[S_x,S_y]=iS_z\neq 0$. This is so because this implies that you cannot find a shared (complete) eigenbasis for $S_x$ and $S_y$. In other words, there simply isn't any state that has a well-defined value for both $S_x$ and $S_y$. As you can notice, nowhere in reaching this conclusion did I have to refer to the expectation value of any commutator.

Now, what the Heisenberg uncertainty principle provides is a lower bound on the product of uncertainties of two observables for a given state. If this lower bound is zero for a given state then it doesn't imply that the product of uncertainties of the two observables would actually be zero for that state. It only implies that the statement of the Heisenberg uncertainty principle is trivially true for the given state. To reiterate the point, a lower bound for a quantity $x$ simply means that $x$ has to be greater than or equal to the said bound. It doesn't mean that it *will* be equal to the said bound. You'd need to have an upper bound as well that is equal to the lower bound to say that $x$ must be equal to the value of the lower bound.